# iOS 8: Launch Screen StoryBoard appears black [single XIB file works fine]

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard

So I tried creating a launch storyboard for my iOS 8 app using [this tutorial](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/)

However, I only get a black screen when I launch my app. A single launch screen.xib file works perfectly, however, when I try to use a storyboard, it doesn't work.

I tried a storyboard with just a single view controller, but it still gives me a black screen, hence I believe the issue is with storyboard files in my setup. Any ideas?

[XCode version 6.4]

EDIT: So I just want to clarify that it is the launch screen that appears black. The main storyboard itself appears correctly when the app has finished loading

Comment: You can only use a launchscreen.xib kind of file instead of splash screen. After that you need a storyboard file which needs to have a initial view controller.

Comment: I'm pretty sure iOS 8 added support for storyboard files as launch screens. At least, that is what the tutorial says.

Comment: Okay, now I checked it from the documentation and you are correct. My bad :)

Comment: My launchscreen.storyboard was also showing only black. I found that it was actually the image view that was showing black, labels would show up fine (I just didn't realize it at first because I had my image covering the entire view). For some reason the issue was due to my image file's name. After renaming my image from launchscreen.png to anything else, like launch-screen.png, it started working. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Read through the tutorial and tested it, and it doesn't say two things:

1: You'll need to add a `UIViewController` to your `.storyboard` file, and then select it as the Initial Controller.

2: If you wish to change more than just the launch screen, you'll have to go to the project settings and set the "Main Interface" to your corresponding `.storyboard`.

Once that is done, all you need to do is edit the UIButton/Label/etc connections to your ViewController classes.

EDIT:

For clarification, you can set a UIView as the initial controller by selecting it in it's respective storyboard file, then opening the Attributes Inspector. The option for 'Is Initial Controller" is towards the middle.

Comment: Yep. Setting it as the initial view controller fixed it. Follow up question though: I also have my actual initial controller (in Main.storyboard) set up as the initial controller. Shouldn't this create a conflict since there are now two initial controllers (one in LaunchScreen.storyboard and one in Main.storyboard)?

EDIT: nvm. Apple documentation states that the initial view controller is the controller displayed when that particular storyboard becomes the app's main interface. Consequently, each storyboard should have it's own initial view controller.

Comment: Actually, no. The "Initial Controller" is the Initial controller of the storyboard, not the entire application.

Answer (score 18):

### For people using UIImageView in the launch screen

Make sure that you are using the image name ***without the extension*** in the attributes inspector.

So for example, if your image file is named **`launcher.png`**, only use **`launcher`** as image name.

This will show the image as invalid (?) in the editor but will show correctly when run on device.

*(Don't ask me why it works this way. Ask Apple.)*

[image]

Comment: Amazing!! the wierd thing that it worked with the extension until I added support for older iOS versions (min 8 instead of 9), that made my storyboard editor very buggy, and removing the extension did the trick. thx!

Comment: I don't know why but this saves my day.. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This answer, along with all the rest, do not work long term. It is so frustrating. Each time the screen goes black, I toggle between using the .png extension and removing it. Does anyone have a permanent solution with a clear explanation why it will work?

Comment: @JeffB6688 Consider this problem as an Xcode fart. :)

Comment: @EhteshamHasan Its actually more than an Xcode fart. I now have an app in the app store that has a black launch screen. While it worked in my final test before uploading, the last build that occurs when archiving it caused it to go black again. I have to believe that I am doing something wrong and would love to find a definitive solution.

Comment: What an utterly idiotic work around (that's a dig on Apple, not the poster of this fix, which kept me from throwing my computer at the cat in frustration). Thanks, man.

Comment: This happen because the LaunchScreen.storyboard accept only images inside Assets.xcassets and the way to refer the images inside Assets.xcassets is the name of the resource without extension.

I think that use the name without extension is a workaround that work.

Answer (score 11):

*None of the answers have all the steps required, hence this exhaustive solution*.

## Storyboard

Start by creating the **LaunchScreen.storyboard**. Xcode > File > New > File... > Storyboard > LaunchScreen.storyboard and add it to all appropriate targets.
In this storyboard, create a single view controller of type `UIViewController`. Do all the magic your launch screen requires, then follow these steps:

1. `LaunchScreen.storyboard` > Show the File inspector > **Use as Launch Screen**
2. `LaunchScreen.storyboard` > View Controller > Show the Attributes inspector > **Is Initial View Controller**
3. Project > General > Deployment Info > Main Interface > **LaunchScreen**
   Repeat for [iPhone] and [iPad]
4. Project > General > App Icons and Launch Images > Launch Screen File > **LaunchScreen**
5. If setup properly, your *Info.plist* should have **LaunchScreen** *.storyboard*, without the *.storyboard* under the `UILaunchStoryboardName` & `UIMainStoryboardFile` properties:

   ```
   <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
   <string>LaunchScreen</string>
   <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
   <string>LaunchScreen</string>
   ```

---

**Notes:**

1. This is *not* incompatible with having legacy images for older devices using Launch Screen File > **Assets**.
2. Pay special attention to `LaunchScreen.storyboard` and `Main.storyboard`. One is used for launch, the other for your app entry point. They both need to have **Is Initial View Controller** set.

Comment: When I do step #3, my launch screen is still black on launch and then after the app is loaded my launchscreen storyboard is presented instead of my main storyboard... so I don't think that step is right.

Comment: Make certain that you do not have discrepancies between `Main.storyboard` and `LaunchScreen.storyboard`. These are 2 distinct storyboards, I clarified the answer.

Comment: I agree with @primehalo. Step #3 doesn't seem right. Same thing happens to me. In fact, it doesn't make sense that the main interface would be the launch screen. What do you mean by ensuring that there isn't discrepancies between Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard? Do you have an example of a discrepancy?

Comment: Rephrasing: it is easy to pick the wrong `.storyboard`. As noted in **2**, you want to set **Is Initial View Controller** in `LaunchScreen.storyboard`

Comment: works like a charm and describes all possible issues.

Comment: Your LaunchScreen is most likely a different storyboard than your MainScreen storyboard. Steps 3 and 5 are confusing, that should be MainScreen. One more tip: make sure that you don't have a `.` in your filename, I made the mistake of separating two target storyboards with a `.`, it is better to use a dash instead, e.g. Launch-Target1 and Launch-Target2.

Answer (score 6):

In the storyboard, which you are using for launching, please make sure that you had selected the option of **Is initial view controller** for the very single view controller present in it.

Answer (score 4):

I Belive I may have had a similar issue that required something a littel different to the above answers.

I created a new launch screen in a .storyboard file, then after it not appearing I resulted to a new .xib file which still did not appear when the app was launched.

I figured out that some of the images I had on my launch screen had an Outlet Collection to an old .swift file. After removing this from the LaunchScree.xib's the launch screen worked fine.

[image: the broken outlet]

Notice the litte warning sign in the outlet reference -> 
[image: The warning]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you set your entry  point and in your general info tap make sure that you have the view set to resize from nib.  Also make sure that in your general tab the start up point is set.  In the deployment info.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Spent way too long on this, thanks Apple! I finally discovered that I had to delete the actual UIImageView in my view controller - not just the image - in order to change to a different image. Tried renaming the images, replacing them in all different ways, deleting caches, deleting the app from the device, doing a Clean before building. The original image was gone from everywhere as far as I could see but it would still appear. Finally I added a new UIImageView on top in the view controller and this took a new image. Then I just deleted the old UIImageView and all was fine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is use the image name without the extension png.

For example, if your image file is named "img.png", only use "img".

This will show the image as invalid (?) in the editor but will show correctly on running.

This happen because the LaunchScreen.storyboard accept only images inside Assets.xcassets and the way to refer the images inside Assets.xcassets is the name of the resource without extension.

I think that use the name without extension is a workaround that work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the black screen instead of my splash after localizing my app. In Localization section of the File inspector of LaunchScreen.storyboard I had only one tick for one localization. So, I added a tick for the second localization and this fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same problem. And i've added the both localizations in `LaunchStoryboard.storyboard`, But still having the black screen issue. Do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Answers by @SwiftArchitect and others are good, but I kept getting the black launch screen instead of my launch storyboard.

The problem ended up being that **my storyboard was losing its connection to my target.**

When I created it, I moved it into a different group/directory in the Project navigator, to keep things neat. BIG MISTAKE! That disconnected it from the target... it didn't matter that the group/directory it was now inside of was connected to the target!

You can tell the difference in the dropdown menu located at:

```
Project > General > App Icons and Launch Images > Launch Screen File
```

When you open that menu, you should see your storyboard as a choice to click on.

***Do not type in your storyboard name manually*** -- that's a sign that the target membership isn't right.

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to add a launch screen, and this procedure got it to appear (thank you!), but now the app hangs there, not moving on to Main.storyboard and viewDidLoad.  I have this:

- Launch screen interface file base name   LaunchScreen
- Main storyboard file base name           LaunchScreen

If I change the second LaunchScreen to Main, I do indeed get to viewDidLoad and the app's main screen, but without LaunchScreen.

Both sim and device do this.  What am I missing to get to Main after LaunchScreen?